# Does .read() return a stream?

Tags: python, stream

What is the technical term for the type return of `.read()` operations in python?

For example:

```
x = open('myfile', 'r').read()
x = stdin.read()
```

What is `x` referred to?  Is it a bytestream?  I'd like to create a function that expects x as input, and don't know how to explain it in my docstring?  IE

```
def parser(stream, ...):
   """ First argument is ??? type, returned from .read() operations."""
```

I've tried Googling, but most results are too jargony.

Thanks

Comment: It depends what kind of object you call `read` on.  If as in your first example you call it on a file object, the answer can be found in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) for `file.read`.

Comment: There isn't a general category for this stuff?  The point is, I want to make a function that accepts input from any .read() operation, and don't know how to refer to it categorically.

Comment: `read()` on IO objects usually returns a string or a bytes object (unicode or str object in Python 2), depending on whether you read encoded or raw data.

Comment: So just saying "str_or_bytes" or something is good enough a name in the call signature of parser?

Comment: For most objects it will return a string, as file objects do.  But there's no general category, because anyone can write their own class with a method called `read` that does whatever they want.

Comment: I didn't really think of that BrenBarn, thanks.

Comment: @AdamHughes I would just call it `content` or something. If you read a file, it contains the *content* of that string. If you read from a HTTP response, you have the response data/content. If you read from a stream, you have stream contents.

Comment: True.  It's really the contents that are important, not the way it's generated.  I'm working on job interview Q and feel like I must not know what I'm doing, but I guess I'll just trust my pythonic hunches from now on.

Comment: @AdamHughes: I think it's better to make a choice and accept either unicode or bytes, depending on what makes most sense. Byte decoding should happen at the I/O point, not in functions called after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either a unicode string or a bytestring, depending on what mode you opened the file in and your version of Python.

- Python 2: Always returns a bytestring (type `str`)
- Python 3: Returns a Unicode string (type `str`) unless `"b"` was in the mode, in which case it returns type `bytes`

Answer (score 0):

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

> file.read([size])
>
> Read at most size bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining size bytes). If the size argument is negative or omitted, read all data until EOF is reached. The bytes are returned as a string object. An empty string is returned when EOF is encountered immediately. (For certain files, like ttys, it makes sense to continue reading after an EOF is hit.) Note that this method may call the underlying C function fread() more than once in an effort to acquire as close to size bytes as possible. Also note that when in non-blocking mode, less data than was requested may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.

What is too jargony about

> The bytes are returned as a string object.

It's a string, containing all the file's content.

EDIT: Adam, Python usually is not strictly typed. Anything that works on a string-like object will usually take anything that has methods/properties like a string.

Comment: I suppose I'm overthinking it.